# What is an easy C++ graphics/game library for raw beginners?

Tags: library, c++, pixel-graphics

I want something beginners can program with from day one.  The old DarkGDK was spot on for this, so that "Hello world" really is this easy:

```
void DarkGDK ()
{
  dbPrint  ("Hello, world!");

  dbWaitkey();
}
```

but it seems to have faded.

I am hoping for a library capable of 2D graphics plus mouse and keyboard interactions.  Free or dirt cheap, which seems to let out AppGameKit.

TIA.

Comment: If you need free & suitable for really raw beginner take a look at python + pygame (not an answer as not C++).

Comment: Yes, it's got to be C++.  But I do use Python in another raw-beginner venue.

Comment: Not a place to ask this question, but a good resource for others - take a look at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/   Personally, I would start with one that you can grow into, not grow out of, but that's just me.